# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate() using current data

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am try to track the number of downloads per click on a website.

**server.js**

```
router.post("/download", async (req, res) => {
let id = req.body.id;
id = parseInt(id);

let doc = await db.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, {downloads: 100});
});
```

> **Note:** This works

But I'm trying to increase the number by 1 each time.

*For example*: Let's say the current number of downloads is 5, how do I do it that if there's a post request. The number of downloads increases by 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const { body: { id } } = req;
const intCasetedId = parseInt(id);
const retrievedDocument = await db.findOneAndUpdate({ id }, { $inc: { downloads: 1 } });
```

A couple things are happening here.

First I get the id value from the the [req](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req) argument using a [destructuring assignment](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring).

I use only const to ensure I do not mutate variable values.

I also use the [object property value shorthand notation](https://javascript.info/object#property-value-shorthand) to skip '_id' key in the search query argument. Quoting mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate):

> Issues a mongodb findAndModify update command by a document's _id field. findByIdAndUpdate(id, ...) is equivalent to findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, ...).

Then I am using '$inc' operator to increment the downloads field by 1.

I would also highly recommend for you to research [eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started)

Comment: You just saved me bro, thank you ❤️

Comment: What if I want to increase by 1 if current value is odd and by 2 if current value if even? Is it possible by one db operation like findOneAndUpdate without splitting in two operations like find and then save?